# ui boostrap typeahead directive doesn't work when wrapped in a directive and loaded dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've a directive that creates an input text element and uses ui bootstrap directive to attach typeahead functionality to the input field.

This input field is dynamically appended to one of the field on the form on dom ready event. *I've to do this since, I don't have access to edit/modify html page generated by server*. i.e -  Dynamically add a typeahead field using angularjs and bootstrap angularjs as well.

I'm using ui boostrap - v0.12.0, angularjs version - v1.2.26 and jquery - v1.8.3

**Problem**: the directive is not working (or may be not correctly compiled or access scope) in IE 11, whereas works perfectly in chrome browser without any problem. I can see the appended elements on form load with no errors or exceptions on the console, however no typeahead magic.

here's the what i've -

```
// added required js references
// initialize angular app
        var typeAheadApp = angular.module("typeAheadApp", ['smart-table', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

controller:

```
typeAheadApp.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function ($scope, $http, $compile) {
    $scope.getCategoriesSize = 1;
    $scope.categorylkp = getCategoryField().val();

    $scope.getCategories = function (val) {
        return $http({
            url: "/some/data/source/url",
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
            }
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.getCategoriesSize = response.data.d.results.length;
            return response.data.d.results.map(function (item) {
                return item.categoryName;
            });
        }, function (ex) {
            alert("ERROR!!");
        });
    };
    $scope.selectedCategory = function (item, model, label) {
        getCategoryField().val(label);
    };
    $scope.updateCategory = function (setVal) {        
        getCategoryField().val(setVal);
    };

}]);
```

directive:

```
typeAheadApp.directive('categoryLookup', ['$compile', function ($compile) { 
        return {
            restrict: 'A',                  
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                            
                    var typeAheadTemplate = angular.element('<div class="form-inline">' +            
                                              '<input id="categorylkpTxt" type="text" ng-model="categorylkp" ng-change="updateCategory(categorylkp)" typeahead="category for category in getCategories($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="selectedCategory($item, $model, $label)" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-loading="loadingCategories" style="width: 345px;" autocomplete="off">'  +
                                            '</div>' +
                                            '<div ng-show="loadingCategories">' + 
                                              '<i class="icon-refresh"></i> Loading...' + 
                                            '</div>' +
                                            '<div ng-show="!getCategoriesSize">' + 
                                              '<i class="icon-remove"></i> No Results Found ' + 
                                            '</div>');
                    var compiled = $compile(angular.element('<div>').append(typeAheadTemplate).html())(scope);
                    element.append(compiled);                       
            }
        }
    }]);
```

init function:

```
function initTypeAhead(){   
    var typeAheadField = getCategoryField(); // some field on the form

    typeAheadField.parent().append('<div id="typeAheadEl"><div ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl"><div id="category-lookup" class="custom-typeahead" category-lookup></div></div></div>');       

    // manual bootstrapping the angular
    angular.bootstrap($('#typeAheadEl'), ['typeAheadApp']);
}

 angular.element(document).ready(function() {               
    initTypeAhead();    
});
```

Any advise or comments ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it the directive thats not working or it's not bootstrapping the ap at all?

Comment: It is the directive that's not working, more specifically ui.boostrap.typeahead directive ... I can check adding alerts / writing on console in controller, directive etc. and see no errors.

Comment: Do u see dropdown (that typeahead adds) in html? Just may be some styles problem (i.e. z-index)

Comment: IMHO the categoryLookup directive is messed up, you compile stuff that could be used in this directive template, unnecessary complication

Comment: @maurycy: can you expand on your sentence, please ? I didn't get it, sorry.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov: yes, I can see, the <ul> <li> tags being created by type ahead directive, but when I type inside the input nothing happens ... also, one thing the placeholder text doesn't disappear on focus and stays there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start fixing it from category lookup directive as it looks rather messy, you are compiling in link method what should be in template

```
typeAheadApp.directive('categoryLookup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div class="form-inline">' +
      '<input id="categorylkpTxt" type="text" ng-model="categorylkp" ng-change="updateCategory(categorylkp)" typeahead="category for category in getCategories($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="selectedCategory($item, $model, $label)" typeahead-min-length="3" typeahead-loading="loadingCategories" style="width: 345px;" autocomplete="off">' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div ng-show="loadingCategories">' +
      '<i class="icon-refresh"></i> Loading...' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div ng-show="!getCategoriesSize">' +
      '<i class="icon-remove"></i> No Results Found ' +
      '</div>',
    controller: 'TypeaheadCtrl'
  }
});
```

#### and then init function

```
function initTypeAhead(){   
    var typeAheadField = getCategoryField(); // some field on the form

    typeAheadField.parent().append('<div id="typeAheadEl"><div id="category-lookup" class="custom-typeahead" category-lookup></div></div>');       

    // manual bootstrapping the angular
    angular.bootstrap($('#typeAheadEl'), ['typeAheadApp']);
}

 angular.element(document).ready(function() {               
    initTypeAhead();    
});
```

Comment: thanks for simplifying. however, it stills doesn't work in IE 11 (works in chrome though) which is same scenario as mentioned in my original question.

Comment: well, it is the placeholder attribute that was creating problem for input text field and I'd to remove it, then it worked like charm. Your simplified code works though :-). Thanks again!